# CSS how to align elements inside a div with 2 columns

Tags: css

In my html/css test page I've a div container with 2 cols.
My problem is that if I insert a div in the left column with the top margin or border, the div in the right column is not aligned at the top but is influenced by the div in the left column and I can not understand why.

CSS

```
body { 
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
font-size: 12px; 
background-color: #f5f6f7; 
} 

.container { 
width: 960px; 
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto; 
} 

.row { 
margin-top: 10px; 
background: #fff; 
} 

.row:before, .row:after { 
display: table; 
line-height: 0; 
content: ""; 
} 

.row:after { 
clear: both; 
} 

.footer { 
height: 36px; 
line-height: 36px; 
} 

[class*="span"] { 
min-height: 1px; 
margin: 0px; 
} 

.span1 { 
width: 958px;
display: table-cell;     
} 

.span2  { 
width: 699px; 
display: table-cell;
} 

.span3  { 
width: 258px;
display: table-cell;
} 

.span3.dark {
background: #616161;
}

.content-center {
padding: 0px;
}

.a { 
background:#FF0000; 
border: 5px solid #00FF00;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.b { 
background:#FF8040; 
border: 1px solid #00FF00;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row">

<div class="span2">

    <div class="content-center">
       <div class="a">LEFT PANEL <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="span3 dark">

    <div class="content-center">
        <div class="b">RIGHT PANEL <br/> Why it is not aligned at the top ?</div>
    </div>

</div>

</div>

</div>
```

How can I solve my problem? thanks

[CSSDECK example](http://cssdeck.com/labs/gtqwrdjf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not seen this style of grid position before.
What so ever.

Do this:

```
.span3
{
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: your welcome, but to be fair Moorthy GK do have a valid point in his comment. I don't think it is the best idea to use display: table-cell; Do what works for you, just a little hint.